# Address family not supported with sockaddr_in

Tags: c, network-programming

I want to do a small ECHO server but this code keep return -1 when passing through sendto and I don't know why.

It always pass into the perror and prints `Address family not supported`
Can anybody explain me why?

Here is my code:

```
sock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0) ;    
memset (&serv_addr, 0, sizeof (serv_addr)) ;
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
serv_addr.sin_port   = htons (atoi(argv[1])) ;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY) ;

ret = bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof (serv_addr)) ;
// ...
ret = recvfrom (sock, buff, BUFF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &addr_len ) ;
if (ret < 0)
{
    perror ("recvfrom\n") ;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
}

printf ("%d received :\n\t%s\n", ret, buff) ;
printf ("Sending: \n\t%s\n", buff) ;

addr_len = sizeof (cli_addr) ;
ret = sendto (
    sock,
    buff,
    BUFF_SIZE,
    0,
    (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr,
    addr_len
) ;
if (ret < 0)
{
    perror ("sendto\n") ;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE) ;
}

printf ("%d char sent\n", ret) ;
close (sock) ;
```

Comment: What's in `cli_addr`?

Comment: @Nebril I just performed a `memset` but I thought `recvfrom` would allow me to send a packet back?

Comment: You should use the length of received data to send back, not the size of the complete buffer.

Comment: @Gerhardh oh my god... thank you, I kinda feel stupid tho

Comment: Nevertheless I don't think this is the reason for your error.

Comment: @Gerhardh it solved the error

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `addr_len` to `sizeof(sockaddr_in)` *before* calling `recvfrom` -- the client address is an output of recevfrom, and the final argument is both an input and an output -- on input it must be the size of the buffer in which to store the client address, and on output it is set by the kernel to the actual size of the address.

Your result is symptomatic of passing a too small value for the address so that the returned client address is truncated and invalid when you try to use it for `sendto`